# sorting a JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have been looking for a couple of days for the answer for this and nothing seems to work. Im kinda new to node.js and I'm working on only the server side to answer POST from the client side. This is kinda like an assignment that i have to do. What i need to do is when the client script, that i did not write, makes a POST request at location '/sort' with parameter `theArray`, i need to sort the array removing all non-string values and return the resulting value as JSON. The client script will send theArray parameter in a stringified JSON Array. So something like this

`{"theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"}`.

I have tried this code here:

```
case '/sort':
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            res.writeHead(200,{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });
            var fullArr = "";
                req.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    fullArr += chunk;
                    });
                req.on('end', function() {
                            var jPar = JSON.parse(fullArr);
                            var arr = "";
                            var par = jPar.theArray;
                            arr += par;

                                function censor(key, value) {
                                    if (typeof value == "string") {
                                            return value;
                                        } 
                                        return undefined;
                                        }
                        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(par, censor);
                        console.log(jsonString);
                });         
                    res.end();


        };

break;
```

but it returns this with an error:

```
undefined:1
%2C%22A%22C%22
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h
    at Object.parse (native) ...
```

Can someone please help me and if you can show me some code to help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to decode POST data according to transport encoding (I believe it's [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) in your case)

```
var json = require('querystring').parse(fullArr).formParamName;
```

replace `formParamName` with actual name used in your POST form. Here is [querystring module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_option)

Comment: Is there any way that you can give me an example of how to do that please

Comment: i had the qs.parse in the place where the JSON.parse before but it returned the samething.                                    Basically the reason i changed it was because what i believe is the qs.parse need is something like key1=value1&key2=value2. And what i putting in it is something like "theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"

Comment: how do you generate form data?

Comment: here i try and explain the best way that i can. i have to right the server side to answer a client script that someone has written to ask my sever 1 question at a time and my script has to respond in the correct way. So to be honest i was only told the parameter will be a stringify json and I just have to take the given parameter 'theArray' value and take out the non-string values and return it back to the client

Comment: can you create gist with complete content of fullArr?

Comment: this does not help much. What do you see if you start raw server with `nc -l 8080` (or something similar)? Can you show headers/raw post body?

Comment: im sorry but i don't really work with github that much but they complete content of the fullArr is - `{"theArray":"[[],\"d\",\"B\",{},\"b\",12,\"A\",\"c\"]"}`

Comment: @AndreySidorov: I'm pretty sure @Chad should use `JSON.parse`, since the client is posting JSON data.

Comment: @LinusGThiel - error looks like JSON.parse input is actually urlencoded json

Comment: Well, if the input is what @Chad has put in the example he's pretty SOL, because that's not valid JSON either. Looks like someone had an array `arr` and did `JSON.stringify({theArray: JSON.stringify(arr)})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseBody (req, callback) {
  var buffer = '';
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    buffer += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    try {
      callback(null, JSON.parse(buffer));
    } catch(e) {
      callback(e);
    }
  });
}

function stringFilter(element) {
  return typeof element === 'string';
}

function requestHandler (req, res) {
  parseBody(req, function(err, body) {
    if(err) {
      res.writeHead(400, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
      return res.end(err.toString());
    }

    res.writeHead(200,{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    var result = body.theArray.filter(stringFilter).sort();

    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
}

require('http').createServer(requestHandler).listen(3000);
```

I have left out the url handling, this is just for parsing the body, filtering out non-strings and I also added the `sort()`.

You can test this with (if you name the file `app.js`):

```
node app.js

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"theArray": [[], "a", {}, "c", "B"]}' localhost:3000
```

*Edit:* This requires the input (request body) be valid JSON, though. If it looks like the data in the question then you would have to write a parser for that format. To me, it looks like somebody had an array such that

```
var arr = [[],"d","B",{},"b",12,"A","c"];
```

And then did

```
JSON.stringify({theArray: JSON.stringify(arr)});
```